# Process finished with exit code 138 CLion

Tags: c, pointers

I want to implement a simple function in C that replaces a string with another but I'm not sure why I'm getting the following error. I'm newbie to pointers

The error says
`Process finished with exit code 138 (interrupted by signal 10:SIGBUS)`

I did some research and found out it has something to do with buffer overflow but I don't see why it occurs here.

I'm using the latest version of CLion to compile and run my program

```
void censor(char *s, const char *search, const char *replace) {
    char *t = s;
    const char *temp = search;
    char *start = NULL;
    _Bool dirty = 0;

    while (*t && *temp) {
        if (*t != *temp && !dirty) {
            t++;
        } else if (*t == *temp) {
            if (start == NULL)
                start = t;

            t++;
            temp++;
            dirty = 1;
        } else {
            temp = search;
            dirty = 0;
            start = NULL;
        }
    }

    if (*temp == '\0') {
        while (*search && start) {
            *start++ = *replace++;
            search++;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How are you calling calling the function? If `s` is a string literal, you can't replace in it. Please post a [mre].

Comment: You can use `strstr()` to search for a substring in a string.

Comment: @Barmar I was passing a string literal to the function `censor("some food", "foo", "bar");` I just realized that I can't modify a string literal so I created a character array and pass it as the first parameter and the error has gone away. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's correct, error 138 typically indicates that the program is causing a bus error which, in Unix-like operating systems, is a fault raised by hardware, notifying an illegal memory access that is not aligned to the addressable memory boundary. Which shows the issue of buffer overflows or accessing memory that the CPU cannot physically address.

The cause could be an uninitialized pointer or an access of a freed memory or may be the replace string is longer than the search string...

Here's a safer version of the code

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void censor(char *s, const char *search, const char *replace) {
    char *found = strstr(s, search);
    if (found) {
        // Allocate memory for the new string
        size_t newSize = strlen(s) - strlen(search) + strlen(replace) + 1;
        char *newString = (char *)malloc(newSize);
        
        if(newString) {
            // Copy the part before the found search string
            size_t prefixLength = found - s;
            strncpy(newString, s, prefixLength);

            // Copy the replace string
            strcpy(newString + prefixLength, replace);

            // Append the rest of the original string after the search string
            strcpy(newString + prefixLength + strlen(replace), found + strlen(search));

            // Now copy the new string back to s
            strncpy(s, newString, newSize - 1);
            s[newSize - 1] = '\0';

            // Free the allocated memory
            free(newString);
        }
    }
}

int main() {
    char str[50] = "I like cats, because cats are great.";
    censor(str, "cats", "dogs");
    printf("%s\n", str); // Output should be: "I like dogs, because dogs are great."
    return 0;
}
```